# PL/SQL parse clob data

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I have a clob data like that:

I have two GAIN AND PAY (it can be more three, four..)

```
<G_1>
    <G><GAIN>14660</GAIN><PAY>0</PAY><Gc>1</Gc><S>1</S><D>0</D><K>0</K></G>
    <G><‌​GAIN>0</GAIN><PAY>0</PAY><T>0</T><S>0</S><M>0</M><W>1</W></G>
</G_1>
```

I want to reach 14660 and 0 (GAIN) and  0 s (pay) seperately. How can i do this ?

Comment: You can do it using INSTR and SUBSTR.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your payload is actually XML, and the `<AL>0</GRUP_AL>` is just a typo, you could use an XPath query like this:

```
select
    xmlcast(
            xmlquery('/G_1/G/GAIN' passing XMLTYPE(col1) returning content)
            as NUMBER
           ) gain
    , xmlcast(
            xmlquery('/G_1/G/PAY' passing XMLTYPE(col1) returning content)
            as NUMBER
           ) pay
from t69
/
```

Check out [the SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd99d/1).

---

So the new payload features multiple instances of `G/GAIN` and `G/PAY`.  The previous solution produces the wrong answer because it concatenates the different instances into a single column.

For situations like this we need to use XMLTable(), like this:

```
select  xr.*
from t69
     ,  xmltable ('/G_1'
          passing xmltype (t69.col1) 
          columns g_set XMLTYPE PATH 'G') xt
     , xmltable( 'G'   
           passing xt.g_set
          columns gain number path 'GAIN'
                  , pay number path 'PAY'
           ) xr
/
```

Alternate [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/36e99/1).  Note that we get a NULL values for an instance of `<G>` without elements of `<GAIN>` or `<PAY>`.

Comment: It seems good solution but i have a question again. If I have two GAIN and two PAY like that: <G_1><G><GAIN>14660</GAIN><PAY>0</PAY><Gc>1</Gc><S>1</S><D>0</D><K>0</K></G><G><GAIN>0</GAIN><PAY>0</PAY><T>0</T><S>0</S><M>0</M><W>1</W></G></G_1>        when i have two GAIN and pay it works wrong, it display 146600